# MongoDB PHP Drivers Persistent Connections Do Not Failover Gracefully

Tags: php, mongodb, replication

So I tracked down a serious issue I am having with respect to failover in a replica set.

Picture a cluster with one master, one slave, and one arbiter.  We use the connection string:

```
mongodb://admin:pass@slave,master
```

When both hosts are up, everything is fine, obviously, but when I begin to play around with taking a node down and putting it back up, unexpected behavior results.

Let's say I take down the master, the slave is then promoted and becomes the new master, the php driver then connects to the new master (the only node that is up) which is what is expected and it's great ... for now.

So now let us take down the new master, and bring back up the old master.  The old master is re-assigned to master role and now it is the only node up in the cluster.  Now the php driver is rendered completely inoperable.  It will not connect at all to any node in the cluster, even though one is up at this time.  I thought maybe bringing back up the other node (thus restoring all nodes in the cluster to up position) would alleviate the problem -- it did not.  So now I have a cluster which is 100% up and running, but the php driver can not connect and it gives the error:

```
No candidate servers found
```

Refreshing 100 times will not fix this, the only solution I found which works is to restart php-fpm.  Once php-fpm is restarted, connections begin right away (until I repeat my test a dozen more times hoping the result is different).

So what it appears to me is that this must be an issue with the persistent connections not properly closing/flushing when a node with an active connection goes down.  So it appears to me (mind you this is my idle speculation based on what I've observed) that in the scenario where both nodes went down and then came back up, the mongo driver is still holding on to the connections which went dead and it is not attempting to remove and re-create connections when nodes come back online.

This is bad and it undermines one of the biggest reasons why we decided to use mongo replica sets in the first place (constant up time).

I am using MongoDB version 2.4.5, the php driver version 1.4.3, and php-fpm version 5.4.9 .

Any idea how I can work around this?  I really do not want to have to restart php-fpm every time a node goes down, but if that is the only way, I will have to configure some type of health monitor to automatically trigger the php-fpm restart -- but again, I would much rather not have to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Haven't had a proper look but does this thread help: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/a1ZX9nyHXP4 ?

Comment: looking into that link now, seems promising, will test a few of the suggestions there and then report back

Comment: Here are my updated findings:  the link suggests wrapping calls to the MongoClient constructor in a while loop with a retry_count.  Seems promising, so I try it, however the problem is that the dead connections that are persisting do not trigger any error at MongoClient construct time, so my retry loop goes fine and then down the line the first time I try calling something like findOne, the driver flips out and returns the error "Remote server has closed the connection" -- which is a great error, however it is being thrown at the wrong time.

Comment: Poop, yeah I think this is a problem with fpm due to the way that process caching works. This is clearly something that needs fixing, I don't currently have a solution, I would recommend replying to that thread, Derick and Hannes are the PHP mantainers.

Comment: How are you instanciating MongoClient?
Are you passing in the "replSet" option to tell the driver this is indeed a ReplicaSet connection, not just two random servers we should be round-robining on?

Comment: If you could file a bug report, attaching a full debug log from MongoLog (see http://php.net/mongolog.setcallback) along with an example code you reproduce this with (e.g. instantiating MongoClient and a findOne() in a loop?).. That would be appreciated! :)